# How can the problem of a GHL custom webhook being stuck in the "waiting" status be resolved?

Tags: webhooks

I have a question regarding custom webhooks, I am trying to send a request to my API and then I want to use response value in the If/Else branch, however for some reason GHL sends a request and it works fine, but it gets stuck and says that Custom Webhook is current action and status is Waiting, though the API has already sent a response.

Do you have any ideas how to overcome this or maybe there are other ways to use webhook response as custom variables in the automation workflow?

[image: Image of execution logs]

As you can see in the image, there are two **custom webhooks**, the first one is just a `curl http://httpbin.org/get` and the second one is request to my API, none of them is executed as expected.

I also run tests that are in the GHL system, and they worked fine for all custom webhooks, however in the whole pipeline, they are always in status "waiting".

[image: part of the pipeline in GHL]

Another thing is that when I add workflow to some contact it for some reason executes the workflow twice and as you can see in the image one of the webhooks worked properly, but two others not.

[image: pipeline execution when added workflow to the contact]

By the way, I have tested my API and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.
I splitted workflow in different workflows and used inbound webhooks as trigger to send data from my API to GHL. So the initial worflow gets message and then sends it to my API, after that other workflows are called in my API using inbound webhooks